# Learning, where to start?

Tags: katakana, learning, hiragana, rōmaji

No, i'm not gonna ask you for tutorials, websites, books.

I've already started learning Japanese, i know a few words and can type them (well, the Japanese driver just puts the Japanese characters there when i type latin letters). However, i hear some different opinions about what to learn first/how to learn.

One site teaches romaji first, so Japanese words written in latin letters. However, others say, thats really bad and teach a few hiragana first before getting to some basic words. Another learning resource expects me to learn all hiragana, then all katakana, before i even start to learn some words.

So the question(s):

What do i learn first? Should i try to learn **all** Hiragana first? Do i need to learn Katakana right after or is it possible to write simple sentences with only Hiragana?

So, as i said, i do not ask for resources, just for some guidelines, what i definitely need to learn before i can get really into it.

(A line about romaji would be great, i've heard that there *is no* romaji in Japanese, thats just invented for non-japanese people for learning(?) purposes)

Comment: I would skip romaji, unless there is a specific reason you need to learn it.

Comment: http://japanese.stackexchange.com/q/354/1478

Comment: Rōmaji is not used exclusively by learners for learning.  It has a number of uses, and for some purposes is better than kana (e.g. discussing morphology).  I think one of the most common uses is probably for typing Japanese into a computer, and most people who do this are native speakers of Japanese.  But it's true that over 99% of the time, written Japanese uses kana and kanji, so you'll have to practice it a lot if you want to be literate.  I personally think it's best to focus on kana only when you're starting out and ignore rōmaji.

Comment: http://meta.japanese.stackexchange.com/q/756/19357 This post lists a wealth of resources. It won't guide you through everything, but it does give you some good learning sources.

Comment: It's ironic that you mention that you input Japanese with Latin characters, but you say you don't want to "learn" romazi. You're already using it.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

You should first learn hiragana and then slowly learn kanji and katakana. There's no romaji in Japanese and katakana is only used for foreign words so it's not as important as hiragana and kanji.